# Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cells heights

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uicollectionview

I am stuck in here trying to achieve a dynamic cell height for my `collectionView`.

So here is my case:

I have a `UICollectionViewCell` xib file which contains the following controls with their constraints to achieve the dynamic cell height :

```
UIButton
UILabel (Fixed Height)
UILabel (Fixed Height)
UILabel (Dynamic Height)
```

as the image below :

[image]

Everything was working fine when the `UIButton` had a fixed height (130) with the dynamic text for the last `UILabel` as Image #1, until I changed the constraint for the `UIButton` as follow:

1. Remove the height constraint (height = 130).
2. add aspect ratio (1:1).

   As Image #2 shown:

Image #1

[image: Image 1]

Image #2

[image: Image 2]

For the code side here is what I did:

1-`UICollectionViewCell` subclass:

```
    -(void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews {
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
}

-(CGSize)preferredLayoutSizeFittingSize:(CGSize)targetSize
{
    CGRect originalFrame = self.frame;
    
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.size = targetSize;
    self.frame = frame;
    
    [self setNeedsLayout];
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
    
    CGSize computedSize = [self systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
    
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(targetSize.width, computedSize.height);
    
    self.frame = originalFrame;
    
    return newSize;
}
```

and inside my `ViewController` which implements the `UICollectionView` delegate:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.arrData.count;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BEBuyCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:self.reuseID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    if([cell isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"BEReceiverCollectionViewCell")])
    {
        cell.isReceiver = YES;
        cell.iType = indexPath.item+1;
    }
    
    cell.object = self.arrData[indexPath.row];
    [cell fillData];
    
    return cell;
}

   - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat width = [(BECollectionViewFlowLayout*)collectionViewLayout itemWidth];
    CGSize targetSize = CGSizeMake(width, 0);
    
    if(sizingCell == nil)
    {
        UINib *nibFile = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil];
        sizingCell = [[nibFile instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] firstObject];
    }
    
    sizingCell.object = self.arrData[indexPath.row];
    [sizingCell fillData];
    
    CGSize adequateSize = [sizingCell preferredLayoutSizeFittingSize:targetSize];
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(width, adequateSize.height + iOffset*2);
    
    return size;
}
```

Note: BECollectionViewFlowLayout is a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to make my `UICollectionView` show 2 columns by customising the layout of the `UICollectionView`

So what I am missing to achieve the correct dynamic height for my collectionView?

Comment: Here is code for the same https://github.com/TechM-Gagan/iOSproficiencyExercise

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gagan_iOS, I took a look at your implementation I can't see any difference but I guess the collectionView treat the dynamic height thing in a different way at least somehow!.

Comment: have look at official document of apple https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318